# Text size in some interface of Windows 11

Tags: display, fonts

I have a computer with Windows 11 with a 27' monitor using a resolution of 3840 x 2160. Initially the text in Windows is so small that I found that I made the text larger by browsing Setting > System > Display > Scale & Layout and set the scale as 200%. And while most of the interface have their texts already scaled to 200%, some interface, like the Chinese Input one which allows me to select the words to input, do not scale and remains 100%. I have tried Setting > Accessibility > Vision > Text Size and adjust the scale to 200% to no avail. Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Text in Chrome is scaled to 200% but not my Chinese input interface, which appears smaller font size:
[image: Text in Chrome is scaled to 200% but not my Chinese input interface, which appears smaller font size]